# Swapping between 2 element in ArrayList

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

I'm new to arrayList and now I am having trouble with the output.
It requires me to take the second char in String Owner compared to other and sort by descending.
I tried by using a variable temp1 to swap 2 of them.

The list before run : (A8,1) (B1,2) (C7,3) (D2,4) (E6,5) (F3,6)

but my output is: (A8,1) (B1,2) (D2,4) (F3,6) (E6,5) (C7,3) (not correct)

```
@Override
public void f3(List<Cala> list) {
    for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
        char max = list.get(i).getOwner().charAt(1);
        for (int j = 1; j < list.size(); j++) {
            char temp = list.get(j).getOwner().charAt(1);
            if (max < temp) {
                Cala temp1 = list.get(i);
                list.set(i, list.get(j));
                list.set(j, temp1);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Please help me what is wrong with this :< Thank you guys

This is my class Cala. I cannot access to Main class because Main's file extension is Main.class

```java
public class Cala {
    private String owner;
    private int price;

    public Cala(){
        owner = "";
        price = 0;
    }

    public Cala(String owner, int price) {
        this.owner = owner;
        this.price = price;
    }

    public String getOwner() {
        return owner;
    }

    public int getPrice() {
        return price;
    }

    public void setOwner(String owner) {
        this.owner = owner;
    }

    public void setPrice(int price) {
        this.price = price;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return  "("+ owner + "," + price +")" ;
    }
}
```

Comment: learn about [Comparator](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html) or [Comparable](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html) and use [Collections.sort()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html)

Comment: Remove `char max = list.get(i).getOwner().charAt(1);` and `char temp = list.get(j).getOwner().charAt(1);` and change `int j = 1` to `int j = i+1` and change `max < temp` to `list.get(i).getOwner().charAt(1) < list.get(j).getOwner().charAt(1)`, and there you are.

Comment: @ArunSudhakaran thanks for the answer. I know where I was wrong right now :<

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I understand that you want to sort the list of `Cala` objects, by the digit in the `owner`, using [bubble sort](https://www.educative.io/answers/what-is-a-bubble-sort-in-java) algorithm. The following code does that:

```java
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Cala {
    private String owner;
    private int price;

    public Cala() {
        this("", 0);
    }

    public Cala(String owner, int price) {
        this.owner = owner;
        this.price = price;
    }

    public String getOwner() {
        return owner;
    }

    public int getPrice() {
        return price;
    }

    public void setOwner(String owner) {
        this.owner = owner;
    }

    public void setPrice(int price) {
        this.price = price;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "(" + owner + "," + price + ")";
    }

    private static int getDigit(Cala cala) {
        if (cala != null) {
            String owner = cala.getOwner();
            if (owner.length() > 1) {
                char digit = owner.charAt(1);
                return digit - '0';
            }
            else {
                return 0;
            }
        }
        else {
            return 0;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Cala> list = new ArrayList<>();
        list.add(new Cala("A8",1));
        list.add(new Cala("B1",2));
        list.add(new Cala("C7",3));
        list.add(new Cala("D2",4));
        list.add(new Cala("E6",5));
        list.add(new Cala("F3",6));
        System.out.println("Before: " + list);
        int len = list.size();
        for (int i = 0; i < len - 1; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < len - i - 1; j++) {
                if (getDigit(list.get(j + 1)) < getDigit(list.get(j))) {
                    Cala swap = list.get(j);
                    list.set(j, list.get(j + 1));
                    list.set(j+1, swap);
                }
            }
        }
        System.out.println(" After: " + list);
    }
}
```

Running the above code produces the following output:

```
Before: [(A8,1), (B1,2), (C7,3), (D2,4), (E6,5), (F3,6)]
 After: [(B1,2), (D2,4), (F3,6), (E6,5), (C7,3), (A8,1)]
```